# How can I reverse an array & then grab the first item with a value higher than 0

Tags: php

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cu_guns WHERE ID=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();
$row3 = $stmt->fetch();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($row3);
echo "</pre>";
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [0] => 2
    [glock] => 200
    [1] => 200
    [tech9] => 200
    [2] => 200
    [uzi] => 200
    [3] => 200
    [tommy] => 200
    [4] => 200
    [m4a1] => 2200
    [5] => 2200
    [ak47] => 2200
    [6] => 2200
    [m249] => 52200
    [7] => 52200
)
```

I want to be able to loop thru this array in reverse & grab the first value that is higher than 0 to use in a script I am writing. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What would you expect the answer to be in this example?

Comment: Easier to do it in the query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//reverse array
$row3 = array_reverse($row3);

//set variable to set first value higher than 0 to
$higher_than_zero = 0;

//loop through reversed array
foreach($row3 as $row_value) {

    //check if value is higher than 0
    if($row_value > 0) {

        //if value is higher than 0, set previously created variable
        $higher_than_zero = $row_value;

        //end foreach loop
        break;
    }
}
```

`$higher_than_zero` will be equal to `52200` in this example.